# Calculating Children in a Hierarchy

Tags: exponential-function

I am creating "children" in script and would like to calculate the number of children before launching the script. I have "width" the number of child nodes and "depth" the depth of the nodes.

- 5 wide and 1 deep = 5
- 5 wide and 2 deep = 30 = (5+25)
- 5 wide and 3 deep = 155 = (5+25+125)

and so on. I "see" the pattern but cannot come up with the equation based on the values of width and depth.

Comment: Everything you need is [there](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Sum%5B5%5Ej,%7Bj,1,n%7D%5D).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's define :
$$N(w,d)=w+w^2+w^3+...+w^d
$$
We then do the following :
$$
w\cdot N(w,d) = w^2 + w^3 + ... + w^{d+1} \\
w\cdot N(w,d) - N(w,d) = w^{d+1} -w \\
(w-1)N(w,d) = w^{d+1} -w \\
N(w,d) = \frac{w^{d+1} -w}{w-1}
$$
So in your case where $w = 5$ you get that at depth $n$ you have 
$$
\frac{5^{n+1} - 5}{4} \text{ nodes}
$$

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

For width $w$ and depth $d$ the number of children $N$ is

$$N = w + w^2 + w^3 + \dots + w^d$$

I am not aware of any simple closed formula for all $(w,d)$ pairs.

Comment: Thanks for this, though I marked the other as an answer because I was able to use the final calculation immediately in my code.